# XCreateGC function performance

Tags: xserver, x11

I've a problem with XCreateGC function performance. It seems that works normal(fast) in several cases, and very slow in other cases:). For more details, please look on this code:

```
void some_function(int dx, int dy, int sx, int sy, int w, int h,
                Drawable src, Drawable mask, Drawable dest)
{
        Display *dpy = QX11Info::display();
        GC gc = XCreateGC(dpy, src, 0, 0);
        XSetClipOrigin(dpy, gc, dx - sx, dy - sy);
        XSetClipMask(dpy, gc, mask);
        XCopyArea(dpy, src, dest, gc, sx, sy, w, h, dx, dy);
        XFreeGC(dpy, gc);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should take into account that X11 is a client/server architecture, and that requests are buffered. Perhaps in some cases `XCreateGC` call triggers flushing of the request queue. Try running your program in synchronous mode and see if it's still slow (the entire application will be slow, bit you need to measure only this particular `XCreateGC`).

Comment: Can you show us a slow function and a fast function? We can only speculate on what the difference might be. ... Also, is there any way to cache your GCs? Or are they completely different each time? eg. calling some_function twice doesn't *need* to discard the GC and allocate another one, unless your code imposes this need.

Answer (score 2):

The key to Xlib performance is understanding when the library needs to block for a reply from the X server. In general, creating a resource (such as GC) does not require blocking; the resource ID is allocated on the client side, and the create request is simply queued up or sent, with no waiting for a reply. At the time when an Xlib call eventually needs a reply, it will have to suddenly stop and wait for ALL requests up to that point to complete, get replies for everything pending, and finally get the reply for the call at hand. This will make one Xlib function look like it's super slow, but really you're seeing the cost of a whole bunch of previous functions, potentially.

XCreateGC should not block for replies, though, as far as I know. It may be possible that it blocks due to a full send buffer? Perhaps you have a flood of requests and at some point your app stalls while it blocks on a full socket buffer, until the X server can catch up and read more requests.

Anyway since this question is old it's probably too late to ask for details, but I think the basic answer is that if you're using a profiler, an Xlib function call may be on the stack when Xlib is actually waiting for or experiencing the consequences of some *earlier* Xlib function call, or just the sheer number of X requests you are making. Most likely XCreateGC itself is not the problem.

Another esoteric reason to wait for the X server can be that another client has a server grab, which keeps the server from processing requests from anyone else.

The key strategies are often:

1. reduce number of X requests
2. do as much as possible before you block for a reply (rough rule of thumb, anything called XGetSomething will have to wait for all pending requests to complete, then gather all replies)

Those are *usually* the main issues, the exception is when you do some truly heavy operation such as moving lots of image data around, then a single operation can be more important than number of ops or round-trip blocking.